# How to extract a changing text from list in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction

I would like to ask for some help as I am a newbie - I am doing a project where I need to extract text from a PDF and store it in a table (excel). While I can extract and slice the text into a list using the pdfplumber, I cannot extract the information I need as it changes every time. Example:

```
['\x00', '\x01', '¼', 'Proof', 'of', 'Proposition', '11.', 'Proposition', '3', 'gives:', 'm', 'ﬃﬃﬃﬃﬃﬃﬃﬃﬃﬃﬃﬃ', 'ð', 'Þ', 'i', 'A1', '\x1bsi', '2', 'pici\x14pi', '¼A1', '\x1bmri2i2', 'ici\x14pi', '¼1\x00mJi2i', ';', 'Ji', ':¼', '\x1bri', '2', 'ici\x14pi.', 'So', 'm', '¼\x00Jiþ', 'Ji2þ4Ji,whichincreases', 'in', 'J.', 'i', '2', 'i', 'New', 'YorkUniversity']
```

I need to store this "New Your University" in my table. But sometimes there is more data like in this example.

```
['cohort', 'level', 'at', 'www.equality-of-opportunity.org)', 'tostudy', 'the', 'effectsoflocal', 'policy', 'changes.', 'HarvardUniversity', 'andNBER', 'HarvardUniversity', 'andNBER', 'University', 'of', 'California,', 'Berkeley,andNBER', 'University', 'of', 'California,', 'Berkeley,andNBER', 'This', 'content', 'downloaded', 'from']
```

As here I would need to extract twice Harvard University and twice University of Berkeley.

What would be the best way to do this? It could be ok if there was one university, but I struggle to proceed with several entries.

Thank you a lot for any of your propositions! :)

Comment: `As here I would need to extract twice Harvard University and twice University of Berkeley.` By this do you mean you want to remove duplicates?

Comment: it is complex problem. You could use `for`-loop to check every element on list `if "University" in word` but this way you can get only `YorkUniversity`, `HarvardUniversity` and `University` but not `New York University` nor `University of California` - because this makes big problem.

Comment: @SeyiDaniel Hi ! Since it's an article, I will need to extract the authors' universities - in this case, there are 4 authors, therefore the 4 universities are needed. Sometimes there is one author, sometimes two and more.

Comment: @furas Hi! This is very true. I thought to try other PDF readers and see the result, maybe it would extract differently. Other idea might be to check with universities databases for matching words - not sure it will help though...

Comment: i think the simpler way would be to join all strings on list to one string and use `lower()` to get string with ie. '...universityofcalifornia...' or `'...newyorkuniversity...'` and then you could use some list/database of universities to check `if "universityofcalifornia" in text` or `text.count("universityofcalifornia")`